# The search function substring within a string

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a substring in a NSString object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613591/finding-a-substring-in-a-nsstring-object)

Something like: If  in "http://test.ru/test/Lala/test.html" is "/test/Lala/" then perform the action

Comment: Please post what you have done so far. Just asking us for the answer will probably not get you results.

Comment: Please refer this SO question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613591/finding-a-substring-in-a-nsstring-object

Answer (score 1):

You can check for your substring like this:

```
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:mySubstring];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    // do you action
}
```