# How do I extract the file name from a path string 

Tags: ios, nsstring

For saving a file on the iPad, I need to get the file name substring (after `sites/default/files/`) in the following path string:

```
sites/default/files/243347_TroubleShootingSqlserver20052008.pdf
```

How would I do this?

Comment: you should be a bit more clear, it hard to understand what you want. Do you have a string already? do you need to parse a PDF?  Which iOS version?

Comment: i will advise you an regex BUT here is the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613591/finding-a-substring-in-a-nsstring-object

Comment: I need the string value after  sites/default/files/ in sites/default/files/243347_TroubleShootingSqlserver20052008.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Set your path to `NSURL *targetURL.` and then

```
NSString *filename = [[targetURL path] lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* pathURL = [path componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
NSString* pdfFileName = [pathURL objectAtIndex: [pathURL length]];
```