# differentiate between plain text and website link and youtube link

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I have NSString variable contain plain text ,youtube link ,image link and link for anther website .
So my problem here is how to extract each one and save in different variables  .

like this OutPut :

2012-07-04 02:45:23.158 mywordpressblog[67403:f803] لتحميل ملفات البرنامج :

http://www.mediafire.com/?ggnkn91qw57t33c

httpv://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3VdzqChORI&feature=colike

Comment: Can you post the string? What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea about objective c , but I know how to use it in java

Comment: ok, in anther words , how can search in string about special words ?

Comment: You need to pull the substrings out of the NSString yourself. Check this post out for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613591/finding-a-substring-in-a-nsstring-object and look at the Class reference under "Dividing Strings" (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)