# extract substring from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I wants to extract substring from NSString. How it is possible.

Example : String is  **abcdefwww.google.comabcdef**

output : **www.google.com**

In the main String, It is not predefined which url comes, It may be google.com or yahoo.com etc.

So I have to find the Start location of w in  **www** and the the last location of  m in **.com**.

So my question is that how I can find the start location of **w** in **www** and the location of **m** in **.com**, so i extract this part

Edited due  to issue :

How we can extract  www.mywebsite.co.uk  from this string asdfwww.mywebsite.co.ukasdfajsf

Thanks

Comment: read NSString / NSMutableString documentation

Comment: a quick google search is all you need

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I edited the question, please check it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a substring in a NSString object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613591/finding-a-substring-in-a-nsstring-object)

Comment: What about asdfwww.mywebsite.co.ukasdfajsf ????

Answer (score 20, accepted):

substring from string like bellow

```
       - (NSString *)extractString:(NSString *)fullString toLookFor:(NSString *)lookFor skipForwardX:(NSInteger)skipForward toStopBefore:(NSString *)stopBefore 
    {

        NSRange firstRange = [fullString rangeOfString:lookFor];
        NSRange secondRange = [[fullString substringFromIndex:firstRange.location + skipForward] rangeOfString:stopBefore];
        NSRange finalRange = NSMakeRange(firstRange.location + skipForward, secondRange.location + [stopBefore length]);

        return [fullString substringWithRange:finalRange];
    }
```

use this method like below...

```
NSString *strTemp = [self extractString:@"abcdefwww.google.comabcdef" toLookFor:@"www" skipForwardX:0 toStopBefore:@".com"];
NSLog(@"\n\n Substring ==>> %@",strTemp);
```

for more information see bellow link..

[help-needed-function-extract-string-string](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/32341-help-needed-function-extract-string-string.html)

Comment: thanks for reply.. I just edited the question, please check it

Comment: thanks, I am trying to implement this

Comment: there is issue What about asdfwww.mywebsite.co.ukasdfajsf ?

Comment: hey mate you can also put condition with this type of .com and .co string to stop searching.. try with these two condition mate also with this .au or .com,.co etc... try with this condition..

Answer (score 7):

You can get substring using following code

```
-(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString *)end withstring:(NSString*)str
{
    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
    [scanner scanUpToString:start intoString:NULL];
    if ([scanner scanString:start intoString:NULL]) {
        NSString* result = nil;
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:end intoString:&result]) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

To call this,

```
NSString *cURL=[self stringBetweenString:@"www." andString:@".com" withstring:@"abcdefwww.google.comabcdef"];

NSString *cAudiolink=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.%@.com",cURL];
```

cAudiolink is the resulted string

Comment: Thanks for your answer.there is issue how i extract this asdfwww.mywebsite.co.ukasdfajsf

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex.

Using this category:

```
@implementation NSString (MyRegex)

- (NSString *)firstMatchWithRegex:(NSString *)regex error:(NSError **)e {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch error:&error];

    if(re == nil) {
        if(e) *e = error;
        return nil;
    }

    NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:self options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];

    if([matches count] == 0) {            
        NSString *errorDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't find a match for regex: %@", regex];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSStringFromClass([self class]) code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : errorDescription}];
        if(e) *e = error;
        return nil;
    }

    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches lastObject];
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    return [self substringWithRange:matchRange];
}

@end
```

You can call:

```
[@"abcdefwww.google.comabcdef" firstMatchWithRegex:@"(www.*\\.com)" error:nil]
```

which returns:

```
www.google.com
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer, how i can extract url mywebsite.co.uk from this string asdfwww.mywebsite.co.ukasdfajsf

Comment: `[@"asdfwww.mywebsite.co.ukasdfajsf" firstMatchWithRegex:@"(www.*\\.co\\.uk)" error:nil]`

www.mywebsite.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution of my problem, after googling. I implement the code below and it's work fine for me

```
   NSString *finalURL;
   NSString *string=@"abcdefwww.yahoomail.comabcdef";

   NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"www"];


   NSString  *tempUrl=[string substringFromIndex:range.location];




   NSRange range2 = [tempUrl rangeOfString:@".com"];

   finalURL=[tempUrl substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range2.location+4)];

   NSLog(@"your URL is %@",finalURL); //prints www.yahoomail.com
```