# Getting word from string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting a string like this separately in a ***loop -> Inbox***, ***[Gmail]/All Mail*** or ***[Gmail Acc]/Trash***

I want to find here only substring *like -> Inbox*, All Mail or Trash and then add into an array(folderarray).

By seeing the above words, there are some strings like -> *[Gmail]/,[Gmail Acc]/*  etc. are coming unnecessarily and i want to remove them if any such strings appear and get words only like -> Inbox, All Mail, Trash

I tried the below code but it doesn't give me the word as expected by following this link [sample string separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613591/finding-a-substring-in-a-nsstring-object)

Could someone help me to solve this please?

```
for (MCOIMAPFolder *fdr in folders) {

    NSString *foldertitle = fdr.path; // it gives Inbox, [Gmail]/All Mail or [Gmail Acc]/Trash
    for (int i=0; i<[folderList.defaultFolderArray count];i++) {

        if ([foldertitle rangeOfString:[folderList.defaultFolderArray objectAtIndex:i] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"Yes it does contain that word");

            NSRange range = [foldertitle rangeOfString:[folderList.defaultFolderArray objectAtIndex:i] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (range.length>1) {
                foldertitle = [[foldertitle substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    [folderarray addObject:foldertitle];
}


- (NSArray *) defaultFolderArray
{
    _defaultFolderArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"inbox", @"draft", @"sent", @"spam", @"trash", nil];

    return _defaultFolderArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED REGULAR EXPRESSION**

```
NSString *string = @"[Anything]/BlaBla";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@".*[^ A-z0-9\(\)]+" options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if(match.range.length > 0) {
    NSString *newString = [string substringFromIndex:match.range.length];
}
```

The regex will analyze your String until the last special character (except the space character, since you want to keep the space in the names of your folders).

I think this can do the trick.

Comment: No, It is not specific "/", it is coming with different chars/strings like that.

Comment: I'm working on a solution right now, will edit this post if I find anything.

Comment: It gives null when folder string is "inbox". And, for "[Gmail]/Sent Mail" it returns only "Mail"

Comment: When "Inbox" comes, newstring returns "nil" to me. Otherwise it worked fine for other strings which has extra chars.

Comment: I found an issue. When I get string like -> Latest POSITION(iOS etc) newstring is returning null again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82717/discussion-between-huunneki-and-user1953977).